# Appending char/wide char to the c-string

Tags: c

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
   TCHAR greeting[50] = L"Hello world"; 
   TCHAR exclamation=L'!';

 //????

wprintf("%s",greeting);

return 0;
}
```

What should be done,  so that the output would be greeting with the exclamation mark? Instruction
`greeting[wcslen(greeting)]=exclamation;`  fulfils the remaining part of array with Chinese characters.
PS. I need to output only "greeting" variable, so the code except of `//????` is unalterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At `greeting[wcslen(greeting)]` there is a null terminator character `L'\0'`, signaling the end of the string. Whatever is besides that point is undefined (chinese characters seems to be in your case). What you need to do is *move* such null terminator to the next position in the array.

```
TCHAR greeting[50] = L"Hello world"; 
TCHAR exclamation=L'!';

greeting[wcslen(greeting)+1] = L'\0';        
greeting[wcslen(greeting)] = exclamation;
```

Note that you have to do it in that order, or otherwise `wcslen` would give a different (indeterminated) value. If you used the standard append functions, this would be done for you.